# Recommendation for learning about stellar astrophysics

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, stellar-astrophysics, resource-request

I would like to know which are the best books to learn about stellar astrophysics at (just) graduate level.

I have a basic formation in general astrophysics but I'm interested in learning about stars, specially their evolution and constitution. I also have a good mathematical formation so it should not be a problem (but I don't care if it focus on the ideas as long as it is a good book and make itself clear).

I found several books at the university library, but I don't know which of them are good (in my situation at least).

Answer (score 2):

Best book I have used for this topic is: An Introduction to Stellar Astrophysics by Le Blanc.

Excellent book, very good introductory start into this topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've look the index and it seems that it is a good book to learn about this topic. Unfortunately I couldn't manage to get it in the libraries of my university. Do you -or anyone- know other references that may be worth to search?

Comment: I think there is a book by Dina Prialnik that you could check out.

Answer (score 0):

I've only read one, but it was my upper level undergraduate text and I thought it was excellent. It was also called "Introduction to Stellar Astrophysics" and consists of Two Volumes:
 1) Basic Stellar Observations and Data
 2) Stellar Atmospheres
The author is Erika Bohm-Vitense.

Answer (score 0):

There's another good and relatively short book (so it's maybe fit as introductory reading) from R. Kippenhahn - Stellar Structure and Evolution.